# Instrument a Google AppEngine application for prometheus

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, prometheus, metrics

Prometheus is a pull-based metrics system using REST. With AppEngine, I might have multiple instances serving requests under load.  These instances are all hidden behind a load balancer.

I have not been able to find how I can collect or expose metrics from AppEngine, unless I push to another service as a collector.

Is there a way to directly instrument an AppEngine application?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, pulling metric data from AppEngine instances using Prometheus is not available. As a possible workaround, you will need to use AppEngine APIs to query the data you require and send it to Prometheus.[1][2].

You can’t easily use a pull model for monitoring, since frontend instances are dynamic and not individually addressable. I suggest to submit a product feature request selecting “Feature Request” as the type. [3]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api

[2] https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/tree/master/vendor/google.golang.org/appengine

[3] https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187191&template=0

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify what you mean by instrumenting an AppEngine application?

If you are asking whether there’s a way your App Engine application can gather its own metrics  or create alerts, you might want to consider implementing the StackDriver Monitoring API [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/

Comment: I'm saying instrument it to report to prometheus.  Prometheus is a pull based system for gathering metrics across systems.  I'm trying to figure out how to set it up with something like app engine that scales itself.